# build failed with first substrate chain

Tags: c++, c++11, rust, compiler-errors, substrate

wanna create my first substrate chain step by step done based their guide [1]: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/

run this command : cargo build --release
but get this error:

```
    Compiling sc-chain-spec v3.0.0
    The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: Assembler messages:
warning: Error: can't open /tmp/cc02CgnB.s for reading: No such file or directory

error: failed to run custom build command for     librocksdb-sys v6.11.4

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully:     ~/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-8abff3284793cb9b/build-script-build (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=rocksdb/
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXX = None
  CXX = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  CXXFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
 
 -- stderr

  error occurred: Command "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-msse4.1" "-msse4.2" "-mpclmul" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DHAVE_SSE42=1" "-DHAVE_PCLMUL=1" "-DOS_LINUX=1" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX=1" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX=1" "-o" "/home/kayvan/developer/projects/rust-projects/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-1d9c3f88cabe429f/out/rocksdb/db/memtable.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/memtable.cc" with args "c++" did not execute successfully 
(status code exit code: 1)
```

Comment: it seems the problem is in relevant with c++ command in the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in arch based linux you need these prereqs :

export OPENSSL_LIB_DIR="/usr/lib/openssl-1.0"

export OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR="/usr/include/openssl-1.0"

for other oses look at ./docs/rust-setup.md

Answer (score 0):

`WASM_BUILD_TOOLCHAIN=nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu cargo build --release` should not need to include the WASM nightly toolchain, this may have been required for substrate v2.0, but no longer for substrate v3.0

Please follow the [guide here](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/getting-started/) and build the [node template v3.0:

```sh
git clone -b v3.0.0 --depth 1 https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template

cd substrate-node-template

# NOTE: you should always use the `--release` flag
cargo build --release
# ^^ this will take a while to do a release build!
```

Comment: at first i tried this one but it didnt help it after that i try the version in my question

Comment: another amazing tip is that it working in debug mode perfectly without error  and ran blockchain and connected to ui

Comment: so you are using v3.0.0 and it's working great now?

Comment: not at all , because of c++ compilation error in rocksdb module that seems my machine related problem and nobody doesnt help

Comment: what is your full machine spec and the versions of all software you are using? all required here: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/getting-started/

Comment: i solved it buddy , your docs has shortcomings

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling using the with-parity-db feature so that rocksdb is not compiled.

If you want an easy life then run nix-shell in the checkout dir and it will install all required dependencies.